Padding and line height issues with mail signature on Outlook App / Windows 10
I've been working on an email signature using MJML and encountered specific styling issues that persist in the Outlook App and Windows 10 versions, despite exhaustive testing and fixes. I've utilized resources like Email on Acid and Signature365 for testing but to no avail. Below are the two main issues I'm facing:
Line Height Issue: The desired line height of 1.15 isn't being respected, resulting in a larger than expected line height across the signature.
Margin Issue: There's an unwanted margin between the bottom of my image banner and the bottom border of the cell, creating unnecessary space.
I've tried several HTML/CSS adjustments based on my research, but none have effectively resolved these issues. Here's a snippet of the problematic code for context:
IMAGE BANNER
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;border: 1px solid black;padding-bottom: 0; margin: 0;">
      <img norescale="norescale" src="https://images.eu.signature365.com/okzkwqlsnchc00xk/img_h5NXWwuCyumAGTbY/v1.png" style="display: block; width:100%;height:auto;padding-bottom: 0; margin: 0" width="100%" height="144" alt="Full width image">
    </td>
  </tr>

LINEHEIGHT
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 30px 20px;font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;line-height: 1.15;">
        <span style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 115%">Sitz der Gesellschaft: XXXXXX</span><br>
        <span style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;line-height: 115%">Registergericht: Amtsgericht XXX, XXXXXXX</span><br>
        <span style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;line-height: 115%">XXXXXXXX</span><br>
        <span style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;line-height: 115%">Geschäftsführer: XXXX. XXXXXX</span><br><br></br>
        <span style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;line-height: 115%">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ut bibendum eros. In nec quam gravida, faucibus risus vel, tincidunt lacus. Curabitur id condimentum augue. Suspendisse erat nisl, mollis bibendum sapien sed, ultrices mollis dui. Sed imperdiet laoreet magna nec cursus. Integer non posuere erat. Aenean dictum sagittis sem, nec egestas turpis dignissim nec.</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

Attached, you can see a screenshot on how this signature should look like.
I am not sure if my request is detailed enough, please let me know if I should add any other information.
Thanks for your help,
Best
Summary of what has been tried and screenshots of the issue

Specific MSO comments, or inline styling for line height with %
HTML Tables
Inline styling
Testing on Email on Acid for my specific version


still extra margin between the banner image and the bottom of the cell
still a line height for my text elements which is too big

How it should look like
How it looks currently
